# Windows notification with button using python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, button, notifications

I need to make a program that alerts me with a windows notification, and I found out that this can be simply done with  the following code.

**I don't care what library I use**

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast("alert","text")
```

This code gives that following alert

[image]

However, I want there to be a button on the notification so I can click it and it will lead me to a url.

[image]

Like this example.

Is this possible?

I just found this website about [toast contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) can anyone help me use this with python?

Comment: You have opted to use a [library](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications) that has gone silent 3 years ago. You're on your own now. Luckily, someone already did this for you: [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh802768(v=vs.85)). You can use [Python/WinRT](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/) for easy access to the Windows Runtime types from Python.

Comment: I mean, I don't care what library I use, I just want it to work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of behavior is not supported in the currently released version of [Windows-10-Toast-Notifications](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/). However, [a contributor created a pull request](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/pull/38) that adds functionality for a `callback_on_click` parameter that will call a function when the notification is clicked.

This has yet to be merged into the master branch, and given how long it's been since the library has been updated, I wouldn't count on it happening anytime soon. However, you can still install this modified version of the library to make use of this feature:

- First, you'll need to uninstall the current version of `win10toast` from your environment (e.g., `pip uninstall win10toast`).
- Next, you'll need to install the [modified version](https://github.com/Charnelx/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications#egg=win10toast) (e.g., `pip install git+https://github.com/Charnelx/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications.git#egg=win10toast`).

Then, you can create a toast like this:

```
toast.show_toast(title="Notification", msg="Hello, there!", callback_on_click=your_callback_function)
```

A complete working example:

```
from win10toast import Toast

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast(title="Notification", msg="Hello, there!", callback_on_click=lambda: print("Clicked!"))
```

When you click on the notification, you should see "Clicked!" appear in the Python console.

**Important**: This will only work if you're using the modified version of the library I mentioned above. Otherwise you will get the error: `TypeError: show_toast() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback_on_click'`.

Comment: Thanks! but can I please ask why I get this error `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.` when I try to install the modified version from `pip install git+https://github.com/Charnelx/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications.git#egg=win10toast`?

Comment: I don't know anything about your environment, so it's tough to say. Was there anything else in the log output that might provide a hint? One thing you could try is updating your setuptools (`pip install --upgrade setuptools`), but without knowing more about the cause of the error, I can't really offer any other suggestions. Here is the full thread that discusses this feature: https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/pull/38

Comment: Thanks! I sort of just bypassed this by using `pipenv`

Comment: That's okay too, it just depends on your environment. Glad it helped!

Comment: Despite its name, the win10toast module doesn't even support true Windows 10 Action Center Notifications. Notably, it doesn't allow you to display a custom UI (say, with a button, as explicitly asked for). It just re-purposes the decades-old Shell interface. And it's doubtful that the implementation's receiver will even live long enough to observe the single supported user interaction: A mouse click, mind you, anywhere, not just over a, say, button.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I have found.

For installing the library:

```
pip install winotify
```

The code that you are looking for:

```
from winotify import Notification, audio

toast = Notification(app_id = "Notification",
                     title = "Alert",
                     msg = "Text",
                     duration = "long",
                     icon = r"FullPath.ico"
                     )

toast.set_audio(audio.Mail, loop=False)

toast.add_actions(label="URL Button", launch = "https://stackoverflow.com")

toast.show()
```

"FullPath.ico" is the full path of the file to put an icon to the notification.

To do this you can press "Ctrl + Shift + Right Click On Mouse" on the icon file and click on "Copy as path". Then paste it into the double quotation marks instead of "FullPath.ico".

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Zroya](https://malja.github.io/zroya/index.html).

Example:

```
import zroya

status = zroya.init(
    app_name="NotifyBot",
    company_name="MyBotCorp",
    product_name="NoBo",
    sub_product="core",
    version="v01"
)

if not status:
    print("Initialization failed")


# zroya is imported and initialized
template = zroya.Template(zroya.TemplateType.ImageAndText4)
#Adds text:
template.setFirstLine("Example notification")
#Adds the button
template.addAction("Ok")

zroya.show(template)
```

Ouput
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJlS.png)

You can read more here: https://malja.github.io/zroya/index.html

Sorry for not posting this sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the accepted answer:

Libraries like [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), [winotify](https://pypi.org/project/winotify/) and [Windows 10 Toast Notification](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/) are either not being updated or lack functionalities like callback on click. Also, they do not support having multiple buttons like dismiss/clear toast, reply, etc.

I found [win11toast](https://github.com/GitHub30/win11toast) library which supports callback function and has many more advanced features than the earlier mentioned libraries.

Here's a simple example with on-click callback:

```
from win11toast import toast

toast('Hello Python', 'Click to open url', on_click=lambda args: your_function(args))
```

Another [example](https://github.com/GitHub30/win11toast) which includes multiple buttons as well:

```
from win11toast import toast

toast('Hello', 'Click a button', buttons=['Approve', 'Dismiss', 'Other'])
```

This would show a toast like:

[image: Image Showing Toast]