# Add buttons in windows notification

Tags: django, windows-10, python-3.9

I am creating 'talking reminder'. Currently its run in web browser.
Now, I want to send notification with buttons when alarm ring. Hopefully, send notification work successfully using below code:

```
notification.notify(title=msg, message=" ", timeout=10)
```

But I am getting trouble to add button 'snooze' in this notification.

I already tried [win10toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668501/windows-notification-with-button-using-python) but it given an error during download win10toast.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: As far as I know this does *not* send the notification to the client (browser), it will generate a notification at the *server* side. So this will not notify the user that is browsing to the page.

Comment: I don't want send notification to any other client. I just want to appear notification in my own laptop when reminder will ring.